# power of a matrix that has a very "big" entry on a column

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, matrices, number-theory

Given a matrix $A = (a_{i,j}) \in \mathbb{Z}^{n,n} $. We say the entry $a_{r,k} $ on the $k$-th column is **big** if $a_{r,k} >  \frac{1}{2} \sum_{i=1}^n\left|a_{i,k}\right| + 1$ (so that $|a_{r,k}|$ is larger than the sum of the remaining column entries' absolute values plus $1$).

For example, take $A = \begin{pmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$, then the first column of $A^m$ does not have a big entry for any $m$, while the second column of $A^m$ will have a big entry if $|m|>3$.

I am looking at the following matrix, $M = \left(\begin{array}{cccc}
0 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 2 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 2
\end{array}\right)$.

I am trying to show that there exists an $m \in \mathbb{Z} $ such that the last column of $M$ has a big entry. I tried to use Matlab (and other matrix calculators) to compute the power of this matrix, but the number got really big very quickly. I was wondering if there is a way to show this without computing the power of the matrix. Has something like this been studied before?

Any insight/alternative approach for this question will be really appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: The matrix is a companion matrix. Perhaps that helps computing its powers.

Comment: How about using eigenvalue decomposition(Diagonalization), $A^m=SJ^mS^{-1}$, then calculating $A^m$ in terms of $m$, get the last column where each entry will be in terms of $m$, and see/analyze to check presence of big entry?

Comment: Thank you both. Unfortunately, the entries of $S^{-1}$ are quite long, so it is a bit messy to do calculations with it

Comment: Thank you for checking this.

Answer (score 0):

As @lhf mentioned that this is a [Companion Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix), we can use it to simplify calculations so that we can only compute only the last column(or any column) only. This will save us from computing power of matrix.

For a Companion matrix $A$, if matrix $A$ is diagonalizable then $A = V^{-1}DV$ where,

$$
D = \begin{bmatrix}
    \lambda_1 & 0 & \dots & 0 \\
    0 & \lambda_2 & \dots & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & \dots & \lambda_n \\
\end{bmatrix},
V = \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & \lambda_1 & \lambda_1^2 & \dots & \lambda_1^{n-1} \\
    1 & \lambda_2 & \lambda_2^2 & \dots & \lambda_2^{n-1} \\
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
    1 & \lambda_n & \lambda_n^2 & \dots & \lambda_n^{n-1} \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Here, $V$ is Vandermonde matrix, $L=V^{-1}$ is the inverse vandermonde matrix and $\lambda_i$ are eigen values of $A$. There are analytical ways to compute $L$, and there seems to be packages/implementations available for that in MATLAB and other languages.

The $k^{th}, 0\le k<n$ column of $A^{m}$ can be directly computed as:
$$
C_{k} = \begin{bmatrix}
L_{1,1}\space \lambda_1^{m+k} + L_{1,2}\space \lambda_2^{m+k} + \space \dots \space + L_{1,n}\space \lambda_n^{m+k} \\
L_{2,1}\space \lambda_1^{m+k} + L_{2,2}\space \lambda_2^{m+k} + \space \dots \space + L_{2,n}\space \lambda_n^{m+k} \\
\vdots \\
L_{n,1}\space \lambda_1^{m+k} + L_{n,2}\space \lambda_2^{m+k} + \space \dots \space + L_{n,n}\space \lambda_n^{m+k} \\
\end{bmatrix}, \quad
c_{r,k} = \sum_{i=1}^{n}L_{r,i}\lambda_i^{m+k}
$$

In MATLAB pseudocode, this would look something like

```
% E is n-by-1 vector of eigen values
% L is the inverse vandermonde matrix
% k (0 <= k < n) is column id

Ck = L * (E.^(m+k))
Clast = L * (E.^(m+n-1))  % last column
```

Comment: Thank you for your time looking into this!